# Is there any way to use a user-defined operator< for a struct to sort QVariants of that struct in a QSortFilterProxyModel?

Tags: c++, qt, sorting, qsortfilterproxymodel

According to the Qt docs for [QSortFilterProxyModel::lessThan](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#lessThan)():

> **bool** QSortFilterProxyModel::**lessThan**(const [QModelIndex](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmodelindex.html) & *left*, const [QModelIndex](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmodelindex.html) & *right*) const `[virtual protected]`
>
> Returns true if the value of the item referred to by the given index *left* is less than the value of the item referred to by the given index *right*, otherwise returns false.
>
> This function is used as the < operator when sorting, and handles the following [QVariant](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/porting4.html#qvariant) types:
>
> [... snip built-in types ...]
>
> Any other type will be converted to a [QString](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/porting4.html#qstring) using [QVariant::toString](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qvariant.html#toString)().

And the docs for [QVariant::toString](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qvariant.html#toString)() say:

> [QString](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html) QVariant::**toString**() const
>
> Returns the variant as a [QString](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html) if the variant has [type](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qvariant.html#type)() String, Bool, ByteArray, Char, Date, DateTime, Double, Int, LongLong, StringList, Time, UInt, or ULongLong; otherwise returns an empty string.

I have a user-defined struct:

```
struct foo {
    ...
};

inline bool operator <(const foo& a, const foo& b) { 
    ...
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(foo)
```

I can make `QVariant`s from this:

```
QVariant r; 
r.setValue(foo());
return r;
```

However, if I return such a `QVariant` for the sorting role then, based on the docs above it won't work - it'll just end up sorting on empty strings.

It seems like what I have to do, to preserve the same order as the `operator <` I defined for `foo`, is come up with a string representation for `foo` which ends up having the exact same sort order.

This is really unappealing. It's clunky and involves code duplication. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what I have to do is subclass the `QSortFilterProxyModel` and overload `lessThan` to do something like `return sourceModel()->data(left).value<foo>() < sourceModel()->data(right).value<foo>();`